# Prometheus - Get unique tag values over time

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to create a Prometheus query in Grafana to count the number of unique tag values in a given time period.

Here is an example of the metric I'm working with. It's a page counter for a website and I'm trying to get the unique users per url filter.

```
page_visits_counter_total{manager="Manager Name",method="GET",postal_code="80021",state="CO",url="/path",user="User Name"} 11.0
```

I currently have variables set in Grafana for most of the labels and was able to get the total unique users, but I'm looking to be able to filter down with a time filter to show unique users the last 7 days, 30 days, etc.

This is the query I came up with to get the total users.

```
count(
count(
       increase( page_visits_counter_total{job="$job", url=~"$url", manager=~"$manager", state=~"$state", user=~"$user", instance=~"$server"}[$time] ) 
     ) by (user)
 )
```

But it doesn't matter what the $time variable is, it just shows the total number of users since the beginning.

If theres any experts at Prometheus out there that might know how to help, or tell me it's not possible so I can stop trying, it would be a great help[image: Grafana Panel]